How do I export await multiple objects in javascript?
There's an example in MDN here,
const colors = fetch("../data/colors.json").then((response) => response.json());

export default await colors;

However, I have multiple constants that are populated asynchronously in a single function:
const _receiversById = {}; 
const _receiversByServer = {}; 
const _sequenceReceivers = {}; // name - k-v receivers
const _sequences = {}; 

// init
async function _fetchAllReceivers(){
    // go to the database and copy data into those consts. multiple awaits.
}

I'm puzzled how do I make the constants the promises that get resolved while the function runs.
I was trying to assign the constants to the promise objects without parameters
const _receiversById = new Promise(); 
const _receiversByServer = new Promise(); 
const _sequenceReceivers = new Promise();
const _sequences = new Promise();

thinking to call .resolve(_receivers...) within the _fetch.. function here and there but I highly doubt it will work and will be easy to debug.
What would be the correct/elegant way to achieve this?

Return a promise.all?

"I have multiple constants that are populated asynchronously in a single function" - even if they were not constant, don't do that. Make the asynchronous function return a value, or multiple values. Do not mutate things asynchronously, even when you presumably wait for something before using them.

"how do I make the constants the promises that get resolved while the function runs.", "I was trying to assign promise objects […] thinking to [later] call .resolve(_receivers...)" - that's not how promises work. You may want to have a look at Promises for promises that are yet to be created even if that doesn't use await yet

Design _fetchAllReceivers so that it returns the four objects you have populated asynchronously. In other words, make the promise returned by _fetchAllReceivers() resolve to the four objects (nested inside a wrapper object).
async function _fetchAllReceivers(){
    // Make these constants local to the async function
    const receiversById = {}; 
    const receiversByServer = {}; 
    const sequenceReceivers = {}; // name - k-v receivers
    const sequences = {}; 
    // go to the database and copy data into those consts. multiple awaits.
    // ...
    // Return (i.e. resolve with) an object that has all the gathered data
    return {
        receiversById, 
        receiversByServer,
        sequenceReceivers,
        sequences 
    };
}

export const {
        receiversById, 
        receiversByServer,
        sequenceReceivers,
        sequences 
    } = await _fetchAllReceivers();

On the importing side, you can then do:
import * as obj from './mymodule.mjs'; 
console.log(obj.receiversById);

Or:
import {
        receiversById, 
        receiversByServer,
        sequenceReceivers,
        sequences 
    } from './mymodule.mjs';
console.log(receiversById);


Looks promising! (in all senses). Is it going to export those 4 objects under their respective names?

Should work. See example I added at the end.

You may want to export const { receiversById, receiversByServer, sequenceReceivers, sequences } = await _fetchAllReceivers(); instead. Avoid default-exporting objects. Use import * as obj from '…' on the importing side if you want to use a namespace.

Alright, @Bergi, integrated those suggestions. Thanks!

Yeah that's what I was looking for, looks cool thanks!
